# Mouse Pointer Flickers and Spins on Windows w/ ShutUp 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, security-center

One of the first things I did after installing Windows 10 (AMD64) was to run O&O ShutUp 10. I made sure all privacy options were enabled (i.e. greened out) except the 'Use Windows Defender' option, since I like and use Windows Defender. Now when I try to start Windows Security Centre the mouse pointer flickers and spins in a most annoying (and alarming) way. The pointer does respond to mouse movements but Security Centre fails to start and I need to log out to get everything back to normal. I want to continue to use both ShutUp 10 and Defender, as they both fulfill certain requirements for me. Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Comment: So, you forcibly modified substantial portions of Windows in ways you're not super familiar with, and are now wondering why it's not working correctly? It's a known fact that ShutUp works rather "permanently". The solution to errors caused by the program doing things you don't want it to is to reinstall Windows: https://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/do-you-trust-of-o-o-shutup10.390552/

Comment: This is specific to Security Center, while is related to Windows Defender, whichremains enabled.

Comment: I do believe the answer revealed itself. Poking around—of all things—the notification icons showed an outstanding Windows Defender notification. Security Center opened normally after that. It looks like the beta-ish quality of Windows 10 is to blame, not any extraneous programs that I thought were.